# Backbone, TypeScript, and super

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I am working through the book "Mastering TypeScript" in which the author demonstrates the use of Backbone to generate the models, collections and views.

I have the following class defined:

```
export class ContactItemView extends Backbone.View<cm.ContactModel> {
    template: (properties?: any) => string;
    constructor(options?: any) {
        this.className = "contact-item-view";
        this.template = _.template(contactItemSnippet);
        this.events = <any>{ 'click': this.onClicked };
        super(options);
    }
...
}
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript will not compile this with the error:

> Build: 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class

Yet, if I move the call to super above "this"

```
export class ContactItemView extends Backbone.View<cm.ContactModel> {
    template: (properties?: any) => string;
    constructor(options?: any) {

        super(options);

        this.className = "contact-item-view";
        this.template = _.template(contactItemSnippet);
        this.events = <any>{ 'click': this.onClicked };
     }
...
}
```

then my event does not fire. The only thing I have been able to do to resolve this is moving the call to super, in the resulting JavaScript code to after the use of "this", thus modifying what TypeScript has compiled.

Is there a way to get my events to work while still adhering to the proper TypeScript rules?

Comment: Worth reading: http://benmccormick.org/2015/04/07/es6-classes-and-backbone-js/

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, Thanks for the link. It was a good read. As this is simply a tutorial, I'm not real worried about it. I was simply curious as to whether or not I could get it to work. It appears that using Backbone, I will not be able to get this to work. Most;y, I plan on using Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "normal" Backbone doesn't work too well, but I was able to get it done with a bit more DIY approach based on the article linked by Ryan:

```
export class ContactItemView extends Backbone.View<cm.ContactModel> {
    static template: (properties?: any) => string = _.template(contactItemSnippet);
    constructor(options?: any) {
        super(options);
        this.events = <any>{ 'click': this.onClicked };
    }

    events(): Backbone.EventsHash {
        return {
          // events
        };
    }

    render(): ContactItemView {
        this.$el
          .addClass("contact-item-view")
          .html(ContactItemView.template(...));
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to use a decorator. Just check it out https://github.com/dsheiko/ng-backbone/blob/master/src/core/component.ts
This @Component is used similar to Angular2:

```
import { Component, View } from "../ng-backbone/core";

@Component({
  el: "ng-hello",
  template: `Hello World!`
})

class HelloView extends View {
}

let hello = new HelloView();
hello.render();
```

The decorator injects specified properties straight into view prototype. Thus they are already available for constructor (super)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the "this.classname..." and "this.events..." out of constructor, and put them in initialize, like this (this may not directly suit your code, but sth similar):

```
initialize() {   
    //... is a list tag.
    this.setElement($("<li />")); 
    // The DOM events specific to an item.
    this.events = {
        "click .check": "toggleDone",
        "dblclick label.todo-content": "edit",
        "click span.todo-destroy": "clear",
        "keypress .todo-input": "updateOnEnter",
        "blur .todo-input": "close"
    };
}
```